# System namespaces missing MonoDevelop on fresh install

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, mono, monodevelop

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I did a fresh install of MonoDevelop on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with .NET Core 2.2 installed (everything updated), then followed the instructions layed out at [Mono Download Offical](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/). I have no errors or warnings during installation.

When I create any type of project or open one, all the system namespaces are missing?

[image]

I have checked here:

[image]

And

[image]

When I build / Clean any project I get:

> /home/ant/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/27259_1/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "/home/ant/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/27259_1//Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (sadsad)

Error

[image: A]

Comment: Have you tried to build the project? Not sure about Mono, but in VS it usually happens, when some packages are not restored yet

Comment: Yes, I get an error about Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets being missing from MSBuild

Comment: New Mono installation might come with latest MSBuild (not 15.0 expected by MonoDevelop 7.x) and breaks everything.

Comment: Would you know how to get an order build, seems if you can only get the one

Comment: It is possible to roll back Mono to 5.18.*, but Ubuntu will prompt you to update (5.20.*) unless you disable updates. Temporarily, the best option is to dump MonoDevelop and use VSCode instead. There should be a new release of MonoDevelop to address this issue, but it won't come soon, https://gitter.im/mono/monodevelop

Comment: Seams the fix is published in 7.8.2.1-0xamarin10-1804b1. Monodevelop work normally for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it temporarily: 
I went to the Namespace/Class options and under Run - Default - Advanced I selected Execute in .NET runtime -> Mono 5.20.1.34
It fixes the problem until i restart Monodevelop.
I'm having this problem since this morning, even after a fresh reinstall.
I am using Ubuntu MATE 18.04

Comment: It also worked by removing the file from the solution and adding it back again. But both of these solutions are just temporarily, sometimes they even don't work. You gotta retry once or twice

Comment: This was a problem with mono its self, mono updated and was using a different version of MsBuild which the IDE could not use/understand. So I pulled the preview repo and it worked as they added a fix there.

Comment: I think I am having the same problem, but am having trouble following your solution. Where is the Namespace/Class options?

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with mono its self, mono updated and was using a different version of MsBuild which the IDE could not use/understand. So I pulled the preview repository, as they added a fix there.

To fix:

purge  monodevelop and mono-devel (with others) and install from here  [Preview - Stable](https://www.mono-project.com/download/preview/) until they patch the normal repository

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Monodevelop under Raspian (Rasberry3)
I believe I can now offer a viable solution:

It's just a setting that has to be done in Monodevelop before you start a new project:

Search under the settings, create and disable the line "create with MSBuild instead of xbuild".

After that all new projects will be recognized without errors.

For old projects the procedure is similar:

but there you should delete the folder ".vs" in the project folder first (better make a backup copy first! ;) ).

Start Monodevelop. Check that the settings are as described above.

Then open the project in Monodelop.
When you open the project, it will be reinitialized and can then be edited and compiled without any problems.